# How do I convert an if statement with or conditions to a ternary statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this code

```
if (ScalarReturned is DBNull)
{
    xCount = 0;
}
else
{
    xCount = (Int32)ScalarReturned;
}
```

which works great but was just wanting to convert to an inline IF -- I tried below but get multiple compile errors.  Can someone assist with this?

```
if (ScalarReturned is DBNull) ? xCount = 0 : xCount = (Int32)ScalarReturned;
```

Comment: What are the compile errors you get?

Comment: `int xCount = ScalarReturned == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (Int32)ScalarReturned;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
xCount = ScalarReturned is DBNull || ScalarReturned == null ?  0 :
                                                          (Int32)ScalarReturned;
```

How it works:

Ternary operator acts a bit like function. Only thing here is, you don't need `return` keyword.

In plain English:

Assign 0 to xCount if it satisfies first condition `ScalarReturned is DBNull || ScalarReturned`, else assign what is after `:`

Comment: So my syntax just did not need the parensethes (SP) or the assignment just needed the value if null?

Comment: The parens were actually fine. Your attempt needed to not have the if statement, and the assignment was in the wrong place. The ternary operator is a separate expression that returns a value based on the condition, and you're assigning the result of that expression to `xCount`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xCount = ScalarReturned is DBNull || ScalarReturned == null ? 0 : (Int32)ScalarReturned;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly using the ternary operator

Try This:

```
xCount  = (ScalarReturned is DBNull || ScalarReturned == null) ?  0 : 
                                                     (Int32)ScalarReturned;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xCount = (ScalarReturned is DBNull || ScalarReturned == null) ? 0 : (Int32)ScalarReturned;(
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator works as follows:

```
condition ? true result : false result

xCount = (Int32)((ScalarReturned is DBNull || ScalarReturned == null) ? 0 : ScalarReturned);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`?` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) on `ScalarReturned == DBNull.Value`:

```
int xCount = ScalarReturned == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (Int32)ScalarReturned;
```